# Instalation GRASS add-ons and its usage in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, add-ons

How to properly install (any procedure!) and enable it to have the ability to run them via QGIS and use them for analyses in this environment?

There is lot useful algos for GRASS mentioned on the [GRASS website](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/) but not available in QGIS. Let's say that tutorial is a bit outdated :)

Comment: The GRASS GIS addons are probably still not supported in QGIS (not sure). Perhaps consider to use GRASS GIS directly.

Comment: Are you accessing GRASS via the plugin or via the Processing toolbox? The latter needs an extra wrapper around every algo you want to use.

Comment: I would like to use it via Processing Toolbox. What wrapper exactly You have on your mind? How to set it up?